# When is it okay to post multiple answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Recently, I decided to look over [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57502/59481) again.

As I was reading all the answers, I started to get the feeling that I had seen an answerer's name more than once. Scrolling back up the page, I found out that a single user had posted multiple answers.

When is this sort of thing okay? If you have multiple (big) points in your review, should they be split up across multiple answers?